# Bootstrap Align Bottom of Images with bottom of Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

Im using responsive grid of bootstrap:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span5 offset1">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                <img class="img-polaroid" src="http://placehold.it/480x300">
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <img class="img-polaroid" src="http://placehold.it/480x300">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span5">
        <p>
            long content here
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I align the bottom of the images with the bottom of the long `paragraph`?
http://bootply.com/73592

Comment: What do you mean by align? vertical, horizontal? Do you want the text at the top of the boxes or below? Maybe try going to http://bootply.com/ and setting up an example? BTW, you need to work in columns of 12 for your row.

Comment: i mean vertical align...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span5 offset1">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                <img class="img-polaroid" src="http://placehold.it/480x300">
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <img class="img-polaroid" src="http://placehold.it/480x300">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span12">
            long content here 
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```